# How do I use the return statement with strings? - Python

Tags: python, return

I am unsure as to why the following doesn't work:

```
def main():
    userInputs()
    print(firstColour)

def userInputs():
    validColours = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'magenta','cyan']
    while True:
        firstColour = input('Enter the 1st colour: ')
        secondColour = input('Enter the 2nd colour: ')
        thirdColour = input('Enter the 3rd colour: ')
        fourthColour = input('Enter the 4th colour: ')
        if firstColour in validColours:
             if secondColour in validColours:
                if thirdColour in validColours:
                    if fourthColour in validColours:
                        break
        else:
            print('Invalid colours.Enter the colours again between red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, cyan')
        return firstColour, secondColour, thirdColour, fourthColour
```

I thought that if i called the main function, It would print whatever I entered as the firstColour?

Comment: give print(firstColor) before break

Comment: i need it to print without having to use print in my userInput function since I'm planning to use it for something else. I've just simplified my problem on here

Comment: then return firstColor or return True

Comment: The function is returning a value, you just aren't capturing it!

Comment: Also you need to outdent the `return` statement. Right now you've got it inside the `while` when you mean to have it after the `while` termiantes.

Comment: @Duncan the outdent basically did the trick! i cant believe i missed that

Comment: This is crying out for refactoring - you should write a function that allows the user to input *one* valid colour, then call it four times. That would avoid the unsightly `if` nesting.

Comment: In your current code, the `else` clause won't have the effect you want... you will only get the error message if the first color entered is not valid. If the second color is invalid, you'll be asked again but no error message will be printed. I'd design this so it checks validity after each entry rather than waiting until the user has entered all four (and then make them re-enter all 4).

Comment: @kindall any pointers on how i can go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print your first colour, try the following:

```
def main():
    firstColour, secondColour, thirdColour, fourthColour = userInputs()
    print(firstColour)
```

When you return multiple values in python in a function, it packs them into whats called a "tuple" which  is a list of values put simply. You have to "unpack" them in order to use them.

There is also what appears to be a logic error in your userInputs function. Your return function is indented too far which makes it always return after the first attempt, instead of retrying.

```
def userInputs():
    validColours = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'magenta','cyan']
    while True:
        firstColour = input('Enter the 1st colour: ')
        secondColour = input('Enter the 2nd colour: ')
        thirdColour = input('Enter the 3rd colour: ')
        fourthColour = input('Enter the 4th colour: ')
        if firstColour in validColours:
             if secondColour in validColours:
                if thirdColour in validColours:
                    if fourthColour in validColours:
                        break
        else:
            print('Invalid colours.Enter the colours again between red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, cyan')
    return firstColour, secondColour, thirdColour, fourthColour
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, you are returning what is called a tuple. If you just want to return `firstColour`, you'd just need adjust your logic to assign `foundColour` with the last found colour and then `return foundColour`

More info on tuples: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 0):

You aren't utilizing the values that you return:

```
return firstColour, secondColour, thirdColour, fourthColour
```

You are returning 4 variables, but not using them

```
userInputs()
```

Replace the above with something like this:

```
firstColour, secondColour, thirdColour, fourthColour = userInputs()
```